# How do you locally override/cancel a shadow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows

In the example below, the style I've defined for `every node` uses a drop shadow. My `a` node uses that default style without modification. However, I'd like to override that style for node `b`, which should have no shadow at all.

I've tried to

- pass `fill opacity=0` to `drop shadow` locally, or
- pass nothing to the option (`drop shadow=,`),

but node `b` still has a shadow.

I've read section 66 of the TikZ/PGF (v3.0) manual about the `shadows` library, but I haven't found a way of overriding a `drop shadow` style. Any help?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={
    draw,
    drop shadow = {opacity=0.5,fill=red},
    fill        = white,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node[
  right=of a,
  drop shadow={opacity=0}, % the shadow is still there
% drop shadow=,            % also no effet
] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is _hack_ that seems to work: `drop shadow={fill=white, opacity=1, draw=white}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Unfortunately, that only colours the shadow white; that won't do, because I may have stuff in the background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A shadow adds a `preaction`. TikZ does not provide a way to remove preactions. In your preamble, you may define your own `reset preactions` key :

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset preactions/.code={\def\tikz@preactions{}}}
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset preactions/.code={\def\tikz@preactions{}}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={
    draw,
    drop shadow = {opacity=0.5,fill=red},
    fill        = white,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node[right=of a,reset preactions] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As suggested by Claudio Fiandrino in its comment, to apply this new key to all nodes in a scope, you may append it to `every node` style:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset preactions/.code={\def\tikz@preactions{}}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={
    draw,
    drop shadow = {opacity=0.5,fill=red},
    fill        = white,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={reset preactions}]
  \node[right=of a] (b) {b}; 
  \node[right=of b] (c) {c};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: However, i don't know how to do it work in several nodes enclosed in a `scope` (like in my answer)  without add `reset preaction` in each one.

Comment: @skpblack: Try the following: `\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={reset preaction}]`

Answer (score 10):

What if we enclose the *node* (or *nodes* that we don't want to shade) in a `scope` with the option `general shadow/.style={}`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={
    draw,
    drop shadow = {opacity=0.5,fill=red},
    fill        = white,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\begin{scope}[general shadow/.style={}]
\node[right=of a] (b) {b};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With more *nodes* we can better observe the effect.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\begin{scope}[general shadow/.style={}]
\node[right=of a] (b) {b};
\node[right=of b] (c) {c};
\end{scope}
\node[right=of c] (d) {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; that works too, but I find Paul's approach easier to use.

Comment: @Jubobs That is the difference between an expert (who knows internal code of `tikz`) and a beginner.

Comment: I like your solution (I've just been reading about scopes, and it's a good illustration).